# QPushButtons in a column of a treeview

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, treeview, qpushbutton

I already have a tree model view that contains columns with a label, text edit, and a check button. What I am trying to add is a push button. 
Here is where I'm stuck:

1. In the "flags" function which namespace will I use?
2. In the "data" function what would be the role of the push button? (for example in the check button case I used the `Qt::CheckStateRole`)
3. In the "data" function (which returns a `QVariant`) what should I return? The button created?

I have looked at other answers regarding this topic and the most popular answer suggested using a `setIndexWidget` however I am not sure how. Last note, I am attempting to do this programmatically not using the UI designer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else, you seem a bit confused about how Qt's model/view Framework is working. I suggest you go check Qt documentation about it: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

The answers to your 3 questions:

1. You do not need to use any namespaces in `Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const`. Just return the particular `Qt::ItemFlags` (i.e combination of `Qt::ItemFlag`) which suits your index. This has nothing to do with the fact that you want a `QPushButton` in your view. I think your are confused by the `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` flag, which make the view display a check box. However that is not what this flag really does, actually it just tells the view to offer a mean for the user to change the `Qt::CheckStateRole` of the index. The default behaviour of the view is to do it by display a `QCheckBox`.
2. There are no roles associated with push buttons. You can use `Qt::CheckStateRole` or `Qt::EditRole`, it depends on the method you choose to display the `QPushButton`.
3. In `QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const`, when `role` is `Qt::CheckStateRole` or `Qt::EditRole`, you may return a boolean which will control the state of the `QPushButton`. However, you should NEVER return a `QWidget` (or derived), the model handles data, not how they are displayed.

A solution:
Reimplement `QAbstractItemDelegate` (or `QStyledItemDelegate`). Rewrite:

- `createEditor()`: create a `QPushButton`.
- `setEditorData()`: set the `QPushButton` state using the index and the role you used in `QAstractItemModel::data()`.
- `setModelData()`: update the model according to the `QPushButton` state.

Set your delegate on your view (`QTreeView::setItemDelegateForColumn()`). At this point you will get a push button only when in edition. You can then call `QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor()` to make it always visible.

Comment: Since you mentioned that I should use the QAbstractItemModel, would I be able to implement it without rewriting my current MTreeModel?

Comment: QAbstractItemModel is the base class for all model classes, so I'm pretty sure your MTreeModel inherits QAbstractItemModel and therefore everything I said for QAbstractItemModel applies to MTreeModel.

Comment: Thank you I think I have a better understanding now. I'm not quite sure what the problem is in this error I'm receiving: return value type does not match the function type

QWidget colorDelegate :: *createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) 
{
 QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(const_cast<QWidget *const>(parent));
 button->setText("Push");
 return button;
}

Comment: Try `QWidget *colorDelegate::createEditor(QWidget * parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) 
{
 QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(const_cast<QWidget *const>(parent));
 button->setText("Push");
 return button;
}`